# Horizontal UICollectionView in UITableView not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my project, I have a `UITableView` with different types of cells.
One of these cells contains a horizontally scrolling `UICollectionView`.

When I run my project, the `UICollectionView` is correctly populated, but I cannot scroll horizontally, clicking and dragging inside this `UICollectionView` only allows for me to scroll the tableview vertically.

The desired behaviour would be that a click inside the cell with the UICollectionView would allow the user to scroll horizontally, clicking in any other cell allows for vertical scrolling.

I'm assuming that I need to overwrite/pass on or disable some OnClick event in this cell however I cannot find the correct solution.

Any help pointing me in the good direction would be greatly appreciated :)

The code for creating the concerning TableViewCell looks like this.

```
@property(nonatomic) HorizontalCollectionViewDelegate *horizontalCollectionViewDelegate;
```

```
- (UITableViewCell *) createHorizontalScrollCell:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath tableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myCellIdentifier];
        MyHorizontalScrollingTableCell *myHorizontalScrollingTableCell = (MyHorizontalScrollingTableCell *)cell;

        UICollectionView *horizontalCollectionView = myHorizontalScrollingTableCell.myHorizontalCollectionView;

        //Link collectionView to its delegate
        self.horizontalCollectionViewDelegate = [[HorizontalCollectionViewDelegate alloc] init];
        horizontalCollectionView.delegate = _horizontalCollectionViewDelegate;
        horizontalCollectionView.dataSource = _horizontalCollectionViewDelegate;
        _horizontalCollectionViewDelegate.data = myData;

        //Define the cells in HorizontalCollectionView
        UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
        [horizontalCollectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"horizCell"];

        //Define flow of AttachmentsCollectionView
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(90, 90)];
        [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
        [horizontalCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

        return cell;
    }
```

**EDIT**: I'm using the same HorizontalCollectionViewDelegate elsewhere in my project (just not in a tableview) and over there it is working, so I assume the problem is not there.

**EDIT 2**: Problem solved, turns out there wasn't a problem (see answer below), will be accepting my answer in two days when I can.

Comment: horizontal scrolling in tableview clashes with cell swipe to delete!!! I suggest you to use collectionview for the purpose of horizontal scrolling but not inside of the table view!!!! if you want to have them both, design ur custom view with scrollview and uiview!!!!

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to overwrite this swipe to delete behavior? In this blog it seems to work but I"m not sure how :p http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved...

Turned out I only needed to add more content to the `UICollectionView`.

With 2 or 3 elements the Cells did not fill the complete view. Because the swipe animation was not showing I assumed there was an error somewhere.

However just adding more content solved this issue.